# Java 11: How to summarize two Single<Optional<>> in java?

Tags: java, stream, rx-java, option-type, java-11

Help please, How to summarize two Single<Optional> in java 11 ?

I am using RxJava but I don't think it means anything.

for example:

```
Single<Optional<MonetaryAmount>> first = someMethod1(a, b);
Single<Optional<MonetaryAmount>> second = someMethod2(a, b);
```

I want to do something like this not syntactically but logically

```
Single<Optional<MonetaryAmount>> result = first + second;
```

I tried to do something like this but it doesn't work in java 11

```
Single<Optional<MonetaryAmount>> result = Stream.concat(first, second)
                                                .reduce(MonetaryAmount::sum);
```

Do you have some idea ?

Comment: Why do you expect your attempt to work? And what could make it work?

Comment: "I am using RxJava but I don't think it means anything." - of course it does. It means you have to understand the concepts of [`Single`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html) and [`Observable`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) in rxJava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `concatMapSingle` and `mapOptional` to get to the present values:

```
Observable<Single<Optional<MonetaryAmount>>> amounts = 
    Observable.fromArray(first, second);

amounts.concatMapSingle(v -> v)
.mapOptional(v -> v) // RxJava 3
.reduce(MonetaryAmount::sum)
;
```

For RxJava 2, use a filter+map combo:

```
.filter(Optional::isPresent)
.map(Optional::get)
```